# How to update result using REST API in HP ALM or QC?

Tags: rest, hp-quality-center, alm

I am trying to update the test results in QC using REST APIs. First of all, is this possible?

Now I do believe that this is possible and should be a fairly straight forward thing. But I am not able to find the right way to do this. Here is what I am doing:

1. Run tests through Jenkins using my own automation tool. This tool gives me the results which I need to populate back in QC/ALM.
2. Now after the entire run, I want to populate the pass/fail status in QC. Lets say I have just one test case for simplicity. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is indeed possible to use REST API to manipulate HP ALM entities. For example we're using it to update execution status of test campaign run in SoapUI automatically into ALM.

Did you have a look at official HP ALM REST API documentation? You should be able to access it from inside HP ALM GUI (Help menu/Documentation library/HP ALM REST API Reference). It describes the API in detail.

You can also have a look at HP ALM forums where this issue have been asked several times [already](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/How-to-access-ALM-data-using-REST-API/td-p/4775940#.VGsn1vnF9NQ):